# SagePay - Woocommerce - Transactions in multiple currencies

Tags: wordpress, transactions, woocommerce, opayo

I have a SagePay payment gateway which has two merchant accounts enabled to it to carry out transactions in both Euro & GBP. I plan on using the SagePay WooCommerce plugin to handle this.

I would like to know for example when the front end user selects either Euro or GBP how will the the transaction be processed with the relative merchant account for that currency?

I see many plugins that take the base currency (GBP in this case) and converts it to a currency of your choice (Euro in this case) using the exchange rate that you specify, however the transaction is still carried out in the base currency. The problem with this is that credit / debit cards will be charged and exchange rate fee.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sage Pay will route the transaction to the appropriate MID according to the currency (and card type, account type etc). You just need to pass an amount and a currency.